# How to get return value on onLoad event

Tags: javascript

```
<html>
<head><title>Body onload example</title>
</head>
<body onload="sum(2,3)">
Welcome to my page
</body>
</html>

function sum(var x,var y){
 var z=x+y;
 return z;
 }
```

My problem is that i want to store return value of function sum in a variable so that i can use later

Comment: store it in `session`, if u want to use it in another page or make `z` variable as global to use it in same page anywhere

Comment: @AshokDamani i want this value on html page

Comment: @AshokDamani i want this value on html page sure

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make it global :

```
var z;

function sum(x,y) { z=x+y; }
```

Now it should be available to you anywhere else in the script.

---

I believe this is what you are trying to do:

**Script** :

```
var z;

function sum(x,y) {
    z = x + y;
    document.getElementById("mySum").innerText = z;
}
```

**HTML**:

```
<body onload="sum(2,3)">
    Welcome to my page Value of 
    <p>sum is : <span id="mySum"></span></p>
</body>
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/MAau6/)

Comment: but i want this value on html page

Comment: then you will have to set it from the javascript.

Comment: instead of using innerText i used innerHtml & it works thanks

Answer (score 0):

A few ways....

```
var a;
function sum(x,y){
    a=x+y;
}
...
onload="sum(2,3)"
```

or

```
function sum(x,y){
    window.a=x+y;
}
...
onload="sum(2,3)"
```

or

```
var a;
...
onload="a=sum(2,3);"
```

or

```
onload="window.a=sum(2,3);"
```

Comment: i want this value on html page

Answer (score 0):

I think you can declare another variable out of the sum function and assign the return value of the sumfunction to that variable. Then you can use the variable on another place.

Answer (score 0):

```
<html>
<head><title>Body onload example</title>
</head>
<body onload="return sum(2,3)"> //
Welcome to my page
</body>
</html>

function sum(var x,var y){
var z=x+y;
return z;
}
```