# How to access to the inner variables of a window.onload in javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, events

I have the following window.onload procesure:

```
  window.onload=function(){
  const v1 = new Date().toISOString();
  const b = document.getElementById("button");
  btn1.addEventListener("click", function() {
  const v2 = new Date().toISOString();
  console.log('elapsed_time (view 1):',v1 +' - '+ v2);
    })
  };
```

I need to use in another function the variable `v2`, how can I get it from outside of the above block of code? I tried to put my  at the buttom. However, it is not working. Any idea of how can I pull `var2`, and `var1`?

Comment: Don't declare the variables/constants inside the function?

Comment: Is there any way of returning them? The problem is that I need to declare them in the window onload

Comment: You can return from this function, but it won't do anything because it's being assigned to an event. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17400962/how-to-get-return-value-on-onload-event

Comment: @evolutionxbox or is there any way of store it elsewhere after that event has happened?

Comment: Have a read of the question I lined. It has some ideas.

Comment: Also I tried to define the variable as a const before the event, and I still can  not get it. Is that what you mean?

Comment: Not as const no. The variables need to be changed. Remember that this event isn't immediate, so make sure any code relying on those variables runs _after_ the onload event.

Comment: @evolutionxbox I put them as vars and I am still getting `undefined`

Comment: And are the functions which use those variables running _after_ the onload event? (I don't just mean "below")

Comment: no I just use those variable once, in another function

Comment: Where are they used? Remember, these variables are being given values when the onload event runs. If the code which uses these does not wait, the variables will be undefined.

Comment: I would like to use the variable inside a function with and if else statement @evolutionxbox

Comment: Call that function from inside the onload function?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to get return value on onLoad event](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17400962/how-to-get-return-value-on-onload-event)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Option 1:** declare the variables in a shared outer scope

```js
let v1, v2;

window.onload=function(){
  v1 = new Date().toISOString();
  const b = document.getElementById("button");
  btn1.addEventListener("click", function() {
    v2 = new Date().toISOString();
    console.log('elapsed_time (view 1):',v1 +' - '+ v2);
  })
};

function otherFunction() {
  console.log(v1, v2);
}
```

**Option 2:** set v1,v2 as properties on globalThis/window

```js
window.onload=function(){
  window.v1 = new Date().toISOString();
  const b = document.getElementById("button");
  btn1.addEventListener("click", function() {
    window.v2 = new Date().toISOString();
    console.log('elapsed_time (view 1):',v1 +' - '+ v2);
  })
};

function otherFunction() {
  console.log(window.v1, window.v2);
}
```

**Edit:** If you could tell us what you are trying to achieve, we could help you solving your problem directly.

Comment: In both cases `otherFunction` could be called before the onload event fires. This would make v1/v2 undefined

Comment: Of course, you need to make sure to call otherFunction *after* onload.

Comment: May you share how you would do that?

Comment: I can share it but its really different the idea. I am measure the elapsed time in each viewed div. Do you want to see that?

Comment: @evolutionxbox To produce an answer to that, I need to know what the author is trying to achieve. What shall the other function do? When should the other function get executed? Right after v2 has been set? Or when a user clicks another button?

Comment: @progmem all good questions I think the OP needs to answer

Comment: Option 2 helped me to access to those variables, thanks